# CakePHP bake custom controller.ctp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakedc

Good morning people,

I am trying to create a custom baking script for cakephp.

What I want is to be able to use the cakedc search function on all of my future pages.
So far I have managed to bake in a working search form on the side of the page by altering the Views recipes.

What I would like to do now is for the baking process to identify all the fields in the tables and output something that looks like this:

```
public $presetVars = array(
    array(
         'field' => 'name',
         'type' => 'value'),
    array(
         'field' => 'status',
         'type' => 'checkbox'),
    array(
         'field' => 'series_id',
         'type' => 'value',
         'formField' => 'series_id',
         'modelField' => 'lookup',
         'model' => 'Series'
    ));
```

in the controller.

In case it isn't clear, this sample table has the following fields:

- id (integer)
- name (tinytext)
- status (boolean)
- series_id (integer, fk)

Is any advice available for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my suggestion is edit the controller for bake:

/cake/console/libs/tasks/controller.php

Comment: Yes, that is what I am currently doing.

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I know this is late but editing that file is a really bad idea. It will break when you upgrade or re-install Cake.